How to access pipeline artifact with Azure Extension?
lets say I have a csv file published as a pipeine artifact and I want to develop an Azure  Extension that uses this to generate a graph later on and display it in a tab.
How would I do the first step? How can I access the CSV file from my Azure Extension?
I have found this example: Example with attachments In the comment it is described how it could be done with attached files. But how would I do it with published artifacts?
Thank you
